# Can you replace "come to think of it with "thinking of it"?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

I've already used "thinking of it." Example:

> Thinking of it, maybe I shouldn't knock on that door.

I made a Google Books [search](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22thinking%20of%20it,%20he%20%22&client=ubuntu&hs=OQJ&tbm=bks&ei=IZreXOm4IYaG8wWtgrnADg&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwipzemauqLiAhUGw7wKHS1BDugQ8tMDCGg&biw=1855&bih=984&dpr=1).

There are similar phrases but I couldn't find a sentence that starts with "Thinking of it,"

So maybe it's not a common phrase? Still, can I be used to replace come to think of it? Or there's a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thinking of it** and **come to think of it** are phrases that people use in different circumstances.

Taking **come to think of it** first, I like Merriam Webster's explanation: **—used in speech to say that one has just remembered or thought of something**

Collins English Dictionary offers **indicates that you have suddenly realized something, often something obvious**

It's an idiomatic expression that one hears in conversation all the time, signifying that something has just occurred to the speaker.

**Thinking of it** (or, more often, **thinking about it**) is likely to be used in a completely different context, generally at the head of a sentence to talk about something that you have reflected on; or possibly to contrast **thinking** with **doing**:

> Thinking of it is one thing, actually doing it is quite another.
>
> Thinking of it has made me realise just how lucky we were.

By the way, one **knocks at** or **knocks on** a door. One does NOT knock a door.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20to%20think%20of%20it
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-to-think-of-it

Answer (score 2):

"Come to think of it" means that you are adding some additional factor to a decision. The standard alternative way of saying this would be "Thinking about it again" (or some variation like "thinking about it some more"). If you decide to take a complete opposite decision, you can also use the standard phrase "on second thought".